# TypeError: Cannot read property 'element' of null

Tags: javascript

it occur error like this `TypeError: Cannot read property 'element' of null`
[image]

I write LinkedList code with JavaScript like this， I define two method `insert` and `find`, but this occur error in find `TypeError: Cannot read property 'element' of null`

```
function Node(element) {
    this.element = element;
    this.next = null;
}

function LList() {
    this.head = new Node("head");
    this.find = find;
    this.insert = insert;
}

function insert(newElement, item) {
    var newNode = new Node(newElement);
    var current = this.find(item);
    newNode.next = current.next;
    current.next = newNode;
}

function find(item) {
    let currNode = this.head;
    while (currNode.element != item) {
        currNode = currNode.next;
    }
    return currNode;
}

var cities = new LList();
cities.insert("Conway", "head");
cities.insert("Rust", "Conway");
cities.find("Rust");
cities.display();
```

I see`currNode` is `null`, but I actual give value to currNode.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but `element` is not a member of `this.head`. currNode is set to this.head.

Comment: I just ran the code above (besides `cities.display();`) in a code snippet and it worked fine.

Comment: Have you tried running the code??